# How to start a windows service from a metro style javascript app?

Tags: .net, service, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have created a windows service to print a image and have written the code in the "onstart" method of the service. I want to start the service from a metro style javascript application.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible.  There is no direct communication between modern apps and the desktop environment.